# redirect() does not resolve @info.app.name@ in Grails when started with gradle bootRun

Tags: spring-boot, grails, gradle

I just upgraded a Grails 2 project to Grails 3 and I have some problems resolving `@info.app.name@` running with `./gradlew bootRun`. In my `application.yml` I have this:

```
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
```

In my Controller I have:

```
def index = {
    redirect(action: 'invoices')
}
```

Running the application in Tomcat, this works fine and `/profakt/invoiceSheet/index` is redirected correctly to `/profakt/invoiceSheet/invoices`.

Running the application with `./gradlew bootRun` the application name is not resolved correctly and the redirect is trying to redirect to `/@info.app.name@/invoiceSheet/invoices`.

I noticed that, if I remove this line from my build.gradle, it works again:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

But I would really like to keep this line, to be able to configure some (db) urls with environment variables.

Any idea how I use System.properties with bootRun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties(System.properties)
}
```

This should append the properties instead of reset them.